# Wallet is synced - won’t allow send

Tags: cakewallet

Title says it all.

Been using cake wallet for years with no issues. As of today my wallet is synced, showing my balance in BTC, but the USD value is at 0. It won’t let me send anything even though the balance is confirmed.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried importing your seeds into another wallet?